# PPT VBA: Automatically rename saved file based on cell value of a table

Tags: save, row, powerpoint, file-rename

I have found a working macro on the Internet that saves my large number of PowerPoint files each time in a new name. The special thing is that the **title of slide 1** is used as file name (for each according powerpoint file).

I also have a table (2 rows, 5 columns) on slide 1 that contains data. I would like to add the **cell value from row 2, column 5 to the file name** to be saved in addition to the title.

E.g. save name could call: **"Title_1234A345.pptx"**

Unfortunately, I can't get it to work.

Below: This is the working macro for the title and what I would like to extend to also save the cell value of row 2 / column 5) in addition to the title -> Data looks like 1234P567XY.

I found on the internet expressions I think I have to use... such as expression.Cell(2, 5), but I am new on this field and can´t get it work.

Working macro below **(only title, without my try to get the cell value)**

```
Sub resave()

    Dim strDate As String
    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim L As Long
    Dim iPos As Integer
    Dim strName As String
    Dim strSuffix As String
    Dim oPres As Presentation
    Const Folderpath As String = "C:\Users\xxx\"
    Const strSpec As String = "*.ppt*"
    On Error Resume Next
    MkDir Folderpath & "\Resaved Files"
    'First match
    strFilePath = Dir$(Folderpath & strSpec)
    While strFilePath <> ""
        strName = ""
        Set oPres = Presentations.Open(FileName:=Folderpath & strFilePath, WithWindow:=False)
        iPos = InStrRev(oPres.Name, ".")
        strSuffix = Mid(oPres.Name, iPos)
        strName = oPres.Slides(1).Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange
        strName = clean(strName)


        If strName = "" Then strName = "Slide1"
        strDate = oPres.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Last save time")
        strDate = Format(strDate, "mmm dd yyyy hh_mm")
        oPres.SaveCopyAs Folderpath & "Resaved Files\" & strName & strDate & strSuffix
        oPres.Close
        strFilePath = Dir$
    Wend
End Sub

Function clean(strIn As String) As String
clean = strIn
Select Case True
Case InStr(strIn, "\") > 0
clean = Replace(strIn, "\", "")
Case InStr(strIn, "/") > 0
clean = Replace(strIn, "/", "")
Case InStr(strIn, "?") > 0
clean = Replace(strIn, "?", "")
Case InStr(strIn, "|") > 0
clean = Replace(strIn, "|", "")
Case InStr(strIn, "*") > 0
clean = Replace(strIn, "*", "")
Case InStr(strIn, "<") > 0
clean = Replace(strIn, "<", "")
Case InStr(strIn, ">") > 0
clean = Replace(strIn, ">", "")
End Select
End Function
```